# Assign values from web method to text box and hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I have written a web method for an auto complete textbox using jQuery.
I want to assign the values selected from this textbox company to textbox and enquiryid to hidden field.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
  //  int usr = ((int)Session["orgid"]);
  DbConnect objdbc = new DbConnect();
  SqlConnection con = objdbc.openConnection(); 
  List<string> result = new List<string>();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT top 10 Company from EnquiryMaster where Company LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
  {
    // con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      result.Add(dr["Company"].ToString());
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No one can give you a proper response unless you post your front-end code too.

Comment: from this method i get a series of records in auto completed text box ....from that series i select 1 and that comes inside the text box.......i want to know how will i get the same values which is in auto complete text box to another text box on same page

Comment: Am not sure with your query but if you want to set same value for another `textbox` ie for example you having 2 textbox `(txtautocomplete,txtbox2)`, so on select record from JQueryAutocomplete `txtautocomplete` is filled with selected value and you want same value to be set from `txtbox2`. if so this can be done by simple JQuery on autocompete `select:` method somthing like **$("#txtbox2").val(yourvalue)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression: `("textbox").val(value)`. It will work